# JUnit - invoke a test method without testing it

Tags: junit, junit4

Soft ball here. Short question for you.

Suppose I have two methods

```
@Test
public void methodA() {//do something}
@Test
public void methodB() {//do something}
```

is it possible to invoke `methodA` from `methodB` without execute again the test on `method A`? 
If not, how can I factorize a code that should be tested at least once (ie `methodA` shold be tested once)?
If is it possible, all the `assertX` will be evaluated again?

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the @Test from methodA? Or is it also intended to be run as a separate test case?

Comment: And if you untest methodA and wrap it in methodC for the one-time test? So you could call methodA from B and C, but only B and C are actual test methods?

Comment: What happens if methodA contains assert? They will be tested when testing C or B?

Comment: I don't know, was just an idea. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the parts of `methodA`that should be used by `methodB`.

```
@Test
public void methodA() {
    commonCode();
    //do something
}

@Test
public void methodB() {
    commonCode();
    //do something
}

private void commonCode() {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The main problem here is that I don't know how JUnit reacts when you call `commonCode()`. Is it `commonCode` tested once? twice? never?

Comment: Wow, it seems to work! After a couple of tries, it seems that `commonConde` is actually executed once! Accepted answer.

Comment: JUnit is only executing the method that are annotated with @Test. Everything else is standard Java.

Comment: Spoken too fastly. The problem is that `commonCode` has assertions that should be tested (and then make the test fails) only once. When `commonCode` is invoked again, it should not be tested and it should not verify the assertions or, if it is not possible, not make the test fails.

Comment: Your assertions are not at the end of the test?

Comment: No, some of them are inside the `commonCode`

Comment: Then you have to provide a flag to commonCode and execute the asserts only if the flag is set. (By the way: you should avoid assert in the middle of your code.)

Comment: Yeah, at this point I think it's the only workaround. Something like `if(toAssert) assertX(...); ... if(toAssert) toAssert=false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using the alternative @Before and @After to perform the actions you want to test again. (Consider posting the actual test, it will be more helpful to give you an answer). Here is an example on how to use these annotations:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("@Before method will execute before every JUnit4 test");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("@After method will execute after every JUnit4 test");
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: well, it's not a part of code that must be executed for every test (neither for the whole class, so `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` are not an option). The option could be to use different classes, but I hope there is another way.